# nodejs - get request body like php's file_get_contents

Tags: node.js, http, request, file-get-contents

In my nodejs code, I use `http` module to get HTTP request and response to user. I want to take `request` body, which I expect a JSON.

Referring from [this link](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/), I apply to my code as following:

```
var http = require("http")
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    console.log("method: " + request.method)
    console.log("url: " + request.url)
    console.log("headers: " + request.headers)

    var body = []

    request.on("error", function(error) {

        console.log("Incoming request error: " + error)

    }).on("data", function(chunk) {

        body.push(chunk)

    }).on("end", function() {

        var content = Buffer.concat(body).toString

        console.log("request body: " + content)
        response.end("IP: " + request.connection.remoteAddress + "<br>" + content)

    })

}).listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port " + PORT)
})
```

I tried to test the code above with following command in Terminal:

```
curl -d '{"MyKey":"My Value"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://myserverdomain.com:PORT
```

But the response is not what I expect (`{"MyKey":"My Value"}`)! Instead it is a code snippet that I do not know where it is from. See below:

```
IP: <MY_IP_ADDRESS><br>function (encoding, start, end) {
  encoding = String(encoding || 'utf8').toLowerCase();

  if (typeof start !== 'number' || start < 0) {
    start = 0;
  } else if (start > this.length) {
    start = this.length;
  }

  if (typeof end !== 'number' || end > this.length) {
    end = this.length;
  } else if (end < 0) {
    end = 0;
  }

  start = start + this.offset;
  end = end + this.offset;

  switch (encoding) {
    case 'hex':
      return this.parent.hexSlice(start, end);

    case 'utf8':
    case 'utf-8':
      return this.parent.utf8Slice(start, end);

    case 'ascii':
      return this.parent.asciiSlice(start, end);

    case 'binary':
      return this.parent.binarySlice(start, end);

    case 'base64':
      return this.parent.base64Slice(start, end);

    case 'ucs2':
    case 'ucs-2':
    case 'utf16le':
    case 'utf-16le':
      return this.parent.ucs2Slice(start, end);

    default:
      throw new TypeError('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);
  }
}
```

Can you show me the problem in my code? And why is the code snippet above returned instead of `{"MyKey":"My Value"}`?

Thanks a lot.

Edit1:

I just tried a more detailed command in Terminal, but still no luck.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"My key":"My value"}' http://myserverdomain.com:PORT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure out the problem, at: `var content = Buffer.concat(body).toString`!! It must be `var content = Buffer.concat(body).toString()`! I missed most important part `()`.

Thanks, everyone